# Show a function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

> Suppose $f(z) = u + i v$ and $F(z) = U + i V$ are entire.  Show that $u(U(x,y), V(x,y)$ is harmonic everywhere.

I know that the two conditions of a harmonic equation are that all the second partial derivatives exist and that the equation satisfies the Laplace Equation $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0,$$ but I don't know how to take the partial derivatives in such a manner in order to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Rasl parts of analytic functions are harmonic and compositions of entire functions are entire. Hence, $u( U(x,y),V(x,y))$ which is the real part of $f\circ F$ is harmonic.